# Basic use of approx() for lookup table with linear interpolation

Tags: r

I have a vector, `my_points` and a dataframe that describes the almost linear relationship between points and values.

How do I obtain the vector, `my_values`, from the relationship described in the dataframe and `my_points` using linear interpolation?

Assume the relationship beyond the last point in the data frame remains linear.

```
my_points <- c(4400, 8800, 13200, 37600, 42000, 46400, 50800, 55200, 59600, 
       64000, 68400, 72800, 77200, 81600, 86000, 90400, 94800, 99200, 
       103600, 108000, 112400, 116800, 121200, 125600)


df <- structure(list(points = c(3000, 4500, 7500, 11000, 14500, 21500, 
                                43000, 71500), values = c(20, 30, 50, 75, 100, 150, 300, 500), 
                     points_per_value = c(150, 150, 150, 146.666666666667, 145, 
                                          143.333333333333, 143.333333333333, 143)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                   -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You say *"interpolation"* but then say *"beyond the last point"* suggesting that you actually want ***extrapolation***, is that right?

Comment: I used the word, "interpolation" because the data frame has point values 3000 and 4500. But if my_points was 3500 a linear interpolated answer would be returned. Even though the data frame ends at points = 71,500 a my_points value of 100,000 would return 699.3007 (100,000 / 143)

Comment: Yes, what you just described (10000 would return 699) is by definition not [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). Regardless of which term, is my answer going in the right direction?

Comment: Got it. I was reading about approx() that's probably why "linear interpolation" was top of mind. So you're telling me that approx() can't do this as nicely as Hmisc::approxExtrap?

Comment: Yes, your answer is fine. If I just wanted the result as a vector in my_values, what would that look like?

Comment: If you see my code, `approx` specifically -- by design -- does not extrapolate. But `Hmisc::approxExtrap` does. I know of no `approx`-like function in base R that extrapolates without you doing the math yourself.

Comment: See my edit, at the bottom is a single expression to extrapolate a single column, returning a vector. Hope that clears it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said *"interpolation"*, in which case you can get:

```r
cbind(
  data.frame(my_points),
  lapply(df[-1], function(z) approx(df$points, z, xout = my_points)$y)
)
#    my_points    values points_per_value
# 1       4400  29.33333         150.0000
# 2       8800  59.28571         148.7619
# 3      13200  90.71429         145.6190
# 4      37600 262.32558         143.3333
# 5      42000 293.02326         143.3333
# 6      46400 323.85965         143.2936
# 7      50800 354.73684         143.2421
# 8      55200 385.61404         143.1906
# 9      59600 416.49123         143.1392
# 10     64000 447.36842         143.0877
# 11     68400 478.24561         143.0363
# 12     72800        NA               NA
# 13     77200        NA               NA
# 14     81600        NA               NA
# 15     86000        NA               NA
# 16     90400        NA               NA
# 17     94800        NA               NA
# 18     99200        NA               NA
# 19    103600        NA               NA
# 20    108000        NA               NA
# 21    112400        NA               NA
# 22    116800        NA               NA
# 23    121200        NA               NA
# 24    125600        NA               NA
```

But you also said *"beyond the last point"*, suggesting you want *"extrapolation"*:

```r
cbind(
  data.frame(my_points), lapply(df[-1], function(z) 
  Hmisc::approxExtrap(df$points, z, xout = my_points)$y)
)
#    my_points    values points_per_value
# 1       4400  29.33333         150.0000
# 2       8800  59.28571         148.7619
# 3      13200  90.71429         145.6190
# 4      37600 262.32558         143.3333
# 5      42000 293.02326         143.3333
# 6      46400 323.85965         143.2936
# 7      50800 354.73684         143.2421
# 8      55200 385.61404         143.1906
# 9      59600 416.49123         143.1392
# 10     64000 447.36842         143.0877
# 11     68400 478.24561         143.0363
# 12     72800 509.12281         142.9848
# 13     77200 540.00000         142.9333
# 14     81600 570.87719         142.8819
# 15     86000 601.75439         142.8304
# 16     90400 632.63158         142.7789
# 17     94800 663.50877         142.7275
# 18     99200 694.38596         142.6760
# 19    103600 725.26316         142.6246
# 20    108000 756.14035         142.5731
# 21    112400 787.01754         142.5216
# 22    116800 817.89474         142.4702
# 23    121200 848.77193         142.4187
# 24    125600 879.64912         142.3673
```

If all you need is the vector of one of these columns, then

```r
Hmisc::approxExtrap(df$points, df$my_values, xout = my_points)$y
```

Comment: Looks like a missed it by a day or two, but congrats on 100k reputation! Well deserved!

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks! It feels like a glacial climb versus meteoric :-)

Comment: Looking at when you created your account I think you were about 2 years faster than me :)

Comment: @GregorThomas Some other users (e.g., akrun, RonakShah) have been on SO for the same time frame and accrued 3.5-7.5x my reps. Perhaps I'm letting my job get in the way.